# Three UpdatePanel objects in a ASP.Net page ok?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have a web page and I want to have three UpdatePanel objects working, based on events coming from several different buttons in different sections of the page.  Is this possible?  The buttons/links are not inside the panels.  I don't want to nest panels, either.  Is there any other object in the Ajax Control Toolkit to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can define [AsyncPostbackTriggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.aspx) for each UpdatePanel.  One word of caution, the last UpdatePanel postback wins.  You can not have multiple async postbacks at the same time.